# Macro Displays a pop-up message if the date in the cell applies today

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of tasks in Excel, I want every time I open the file, and there is a cell with a date that applies today, will pop a message with the contents of the task that applies today

I tried to do this code, but it did not work

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each cell In Range("A4:A500")
        If cell.Value - today Then
            MsgBox "Here should be the text in column B"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Your `If` statement is incomplete. See https://www.thecodingguys.net/tutorials/visualbasic/vb-if-statement and https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-if/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement

Comment: VBA's Today is `Date` so `If cell.Value = Date Then`

Comment: Thanks for the willingness to help, I do not see what's wrong with me, I do not really understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample has a worksheet named ***list***:

[image]

This code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each cell In Sheets("list").Range("A4:A500")
        If cell.Value = Date Then
            MsgBox cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

will show ***gold***

**Note:**

- we use `Date()` rather than `Today()`
- we specify the worksheet to examine
- we use `Offset` to get the column **B** contents

**EDIT#1:**

Because it is workbook code, it is very easy to install and use:

1. right-click `ThisWorkbook` in the left-hand pane of the VBE

[image]

2. select View Code
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (workbook code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Your code looks great!
But it does not work for me
Do I need to paste in the module?
Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @slomo  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

TodayD = Date

'define sheet
With Worksheets(1).Range("A4:A500")
    Set c = .Find(Date, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            MsgBox "Here should be the text in column B: " & firstAddress
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Better late than never

```
Option Explicit
Sub TodaysTasks()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Description
  'In a specified worksheet or the ActiveSheet, searches a specified one column
  'range and looks for today's date values and when found writes the values of
  'the next adjacent column to a string and finally outputs the string to a
  'MsgBox and to the Immediate window.
'Arguments as constants
  'cStrWorksheetName
    'The name of the worksheet. If "" then the ActiveSheet object is used.
  'cStrRange
    'The range where to search.
  'cStrTitle
    'The title of the resulting string
'Results
  'A string containing the title and the matching values of the second column.

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Customize BEGIN -----------------------
  Const cStrWorksheetName = "" 'Worksheet name. If "" then ActiveSheet.
  Const cStrRange = "A4:A500"
  Const cStrTitle = "My today's tasks"
'Customize END -------------------------

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Dim oWb As Workbook
  Dim oWs As Worksheet
  Dim rRng As Range
  Dim loF1 As Long 'Rows Counter
  Dim strTasks As String

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Set oWb = ActiveWorkbook
  If cStrWorksheetName = "" Then
    Set oWs = oWb.ActiveSheet
   Else
    Set oWs = oWb.Worksheets(cStrWorksheetName)
  End If
  Set rRng = oWs.Range(cStrRange)
  'Set the title
  strTasks = cStrTitle & vbCrLf

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  'Loop through all cells (rows) in first column.
  For loF1 = 1 To oWs.Range(cStrRange).Rows.Count
  'Check if value in first column is todays date.
    If rRng(loF1, 1).Value = Date Then 'It is today's date.
      'Write value in second column to the string.
      strTasks = strTasks & vbCrLf & rRng(loF1, 2).Value
'     Else 'It is not today's date.
      'skip the row
    End If
  Next

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  MsgBox strTasks
  Debug.Print strTasks

End Sub
```